# how to send image via ajax and FormData()

Tags: ajax, form-data

I've been struggling with this all day and finally found out...

this DOESN'T WORK for me:

```
formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('img', imgInputElement.files[0]);
```

but this DOES:

```
formdata = new FormData(formElement);
formdata.append('img', imgInputElement.files[0]);
```

Now my ajax calls are finally working, but I don't really know why I have to pass the 'form' type element in as the constructor, when I'm just adding the data manually anyway with formdata.append(). It was my understanding that passing in a form element as an argument to the constructor should automatically run append() on every input within the form.  Anyone care to explain?